# How ad servers works on preroll, postroll video advertising?

Tags: ads, advertisement-server

How can an ad server generate code for pre roll videos without knowing about the actual video and player used by the publisher website? Or else, whether ad server wants to ask for these details to publisher before generating code?

Comment: It generates code because the publisher website requested code to be generated. I am not sure what your question is.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need to know what and all information an ad server will ask from publisher so that they can generate code

Answer (score 0):

i dont think they ask publishers anythink about video. Maybe they categorise the publisher websites and trying to show related pre-rolls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the ad server is not asking about the main video to a publisher, how can ad server generate code without knowing the actual video played by publisher website?

Answer (score 0):

This is why VAST xml schema was created: to have a standardized way for ad servers to 'talk' video players without having to know anything about that player. Google 'IAB VAST' to learn more.

Before VAST, ad servers needed specific code for every publisher and every video player to send a response that player would understand.

VPAID is the way the *ad unit* communicates with the video player.

Hope that helps.